# Configurando CakePHP com Composer

Tags: cakephp-2, composer

Instalei o CakePHP em um servidor MAMP (Mac OS X) e configurando o [plugin cakephp-upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) havia a dica de instalar o plugin usando o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Configurei meu `composer.json` da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "name": "designliquido/loja",
    "description": "Loja",
    "type": "site",
    "keywords": ["shop"],
    "homepage": "http://www.minhaloja.com.br",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Design Líquido",
            "homepage": "http://www.designliquido.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.8",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "josegonzalez/cakephp-upload": "1.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit" : "2.2.*"
    },
    "bin": [
        "lib/Cake/Console/cake"
    ]
}
```

Ao executar:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Tudo funcionou ok, mas o Composer instalou os plugins no diretório raiz do projeto (onde está o arquivo `composer.json`), e não em `app/Plugin`, que é o correto.

Há alguma maneira de especificar o diretório de instalação dos Plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o github do projeto, esse é o caminho correto da instalação via composer.

> Because this plugin has the type cakephp-plugin set in it's own composer.json, composer knows to install it inside your /Plugins directory, rather than in the usual vendors file. It is recommended that you add /Plugins/Upload to your .gitignore file.

A documentação do projeto diz que o plugin tem um arquivo composer  com a configuração `type: cakephp-plugin`, o que é verdade olhando o repositório do projeto.

Segundo a [documentação do composer](https://github.com/composer/installers#example-composerjson-file), esse realmente é o comportamento dessa configuração.

> This is an example for a CakePHP plugin. The only important parts to set in your composer.json file are "type": "cakephp-plugin" which describes what your package is and "require": { "composer/installers": "~1.0" } which tells composer to load the custom installers.

```
{
    "name": "you/ftp",
    "type": "cakephp-plugin",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

> This would install your package to the Plugin/Ftp/ folder of a CakePHP app when a user runs php composer.phar install.

Acredito que o CakePHP deva funcionar dessa forma, embora eu nunca tenha usado.

Segundo a documentação do CakePHP

> Autoloading Plugin Classes
>   When using bake for creating a plugin or when installing a plugin using Composer, you don’t typically need to make any changes to your application in order to make CakePHP recognize the classes that live inside it.
>
> In any other cases you may need to modify your application’s composer.json file to contain the following information:

```
"psr-4": {
   (...)
    "MyPlugin\\": "./plugins/MyPlugin/src",
    "MyPlugin\\Test\\": "./plugins/MyPlugin/tests"
}
```

> Additionally you will need to tell Composer to refresh its autoloading cache:
>
> ```
> $ php composer.phar dumpautoload
> ```
>
> If you are unable to use Composer for any reason, you can also use a fallback >autoloading for your plugin:
>
> ```
> Plugin::load('ContactManager', ['autoload' => true]);
> ```

Caso você realmente necessite trocar o path da onde o composer instala os plugins do CakePHP, seria só adicionar a configuração a seguir no seu arquivo composer.json

> A package type can have a custom installation path with a type: prefix.

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "your/custom/path/{$name}/": ["type:cakephp-plugin"]
        }
    }
}
```

Ou você pode mudar o caminho de instalação de um único pacote

> If you are consuming a package that uses the composer/installers you can override the install path with the following extra in your composer.json:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "your/custom/path/{$name}/": ["shama/ftp", "vendor/package"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Era esta última parte que eu queria. Obrigado!

Comment: Só não faz muito sentido Você ter que fazer isso para um plugin do próprio cakephp mas blz.

Comment: @Édipo Costa Rebouças como instalar o composer. Tentei buscar na internet e fazer no git bass, mas n'ao consegui.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md itens 3 e 4